# Google Sheets API Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

<s>Написал</s> Скопировал код:

```
import httplib2
import os

from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

try:
    scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",]
    secret_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "client_secret.json")

    spreadsheet_id = "..."
    range_name = "Sheet1!B3"

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(secret_file, scopes=scopes)
    service = discovery.build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)

    values=service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,range=range_name,).execute()

    print(values.get('values'))


except OSError as e:
    print(e)
```

Когда запускаю, выдает вот это:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    values=service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,range=range_name,).execute()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 920, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/.../values/Sheet1%21B3?alt=json returned "Unable to parse range: Sheet1!B3". Details: "Unable to parse range: Sheet1!B3">
```

Когда сам перехожу по ссылке пишет:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

**Как исправить???**

Comment: В тексте ошибки написано "Запрос ожидает действительный ключ для API". Я не работал с Google API, но на примере VK API есть несколько вопросов: имеется ли вообще у вас токен(ключ) для работы? Ввели ли вы его правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно получить ключ сервисного аккаунта, судя по коду. Чтобы получить ключ для сервисного аккаунта, нужно

1. Перейти сюда https://console.cloud.google.com
2. Создаете или выбираете проект [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Проверьте, что вы выбрали нужный проект. Идите в **API & Services** > **Library** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Найдите там Sheets API и включите их [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Проверьте, что вы выбрали нужный проект. Идите в API & Services > Credentials [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Запустите мастер создания аккаунта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. Укажите и нажмите только то, что на картинке. Опции не нужны [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
8. Обновите страницу или идите в API & Services > Credentials еще раз или в IAM & Admin > Service Accounts (пути равносильны). Требуется немного времени, чтобы аккаунт был создан. Выберите созданный аккаунт. Перейдите в Keys. Создайте новый ключ JSON и сохраните его в `client_secret.json` как у вас указано [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Важно**. В п.7 был создан сервисный аккаунт и почта к нему. Эту почту необходимо добавить как читателя к вашей Таблице, чтобы получить доступ к данным.

Comment: Спасибо! Простите за мою надоедливость, но нечего не изменилось. Все так-же пишет ошибку: "Unable to parse range: '5'!I3"
[скрины](https://ru.files.fm/u/pndrn8r85)